# How many circular necklaces can be made with the length of p (a prime number), that can be created by connecting n different types of beads together

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Given an unlimited number of beads of n different types, how many circular necklaces are there, with the length of p (a prime number), that can be created by connecting the beads together?

Note that two necklaces are identical if we can get one of the necklaces by rounding the other necklace.

I have an approach; First we count how many necklaces there to exist with the length of p and of n different beads and then we divide all the possibilities by the number of equivalence classes. I believe that there are 360/p different equivalence classes.

I am not certain whether this is the right approach, and also is this the right number of equivalence classes?

Disclaimer: I am asking this question for a friend who does not know how to use this site and cannot formulate a question that is comprehensible in English, so I apologize for any vague point.

Comment: Wher does the number $360$ come from?

Comment: Are necklaces that are mirror images identical? Because one can flip a necklace in 3-dimensional space...

Comment: See also the [necklace-counting proof of Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_Fermat%27s_little_theorem#Proof_by_counting_necklaces).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we first ignore the equivalences, we choose among $n$ types for each of $p$ bead positions $0,1,\ldots,p-1$. This gives us $n^p$ distinct necklaces that we can describe as $p$-tuples $a=(a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_{p-1})$ where $a_i\in\{0,2,\ldots,n-1\}$.

For a necklace $a$ we define $R(a)=(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_{p-1},a_0)$ as rotated (by one position) necklace. The equivalence class $[a]$  of a necklace $a$ is the set of all necklaces of the form $R^k(a)$, $k\in\Bbb Z$. How big is $[a]$?
Clearly $R^p$ is the identity map, hence the equivalence consists really only of the $R^k(a)$, $0\le k<p$. But even these need not all be different.
Assume $R^i(a)=R^j(a)$ for some $i,j$ with  $0\le i<j<p$. Then with $d:=j-i$, we also have $a=R^d(a)$ as well as $a=R^{kd\bmod p}(a)$. As $d$ is not a multilple of $p$, there exists $k$ with $kd\bmod p=1$. It follows that $a=R(a)$ and then also $a=R^2(a)=R^3(a)=\ldots$, i.e., $[a]$ consists of $a$ only. We conclude that $[a]$ either consists of $p$ distinct necklaces or of only one necklace. Clearly, the latter happens precisely  for the $n$ "constant" necklaces $(c,c,\ldots,c)$.
So to count all equivalence clases, we count the $n$ constant necklaces and then note that the remaining $n^p-n$ necklaces come in groups of $p$. We end up with
$$ n+\frac{n^p-n}p.$$
Incidentally, this expression must give an integer so that as a side-effect we have shown that $n^p-n$ is a multiple of $p$ if  $n\in\Bbb N$ and $p$ is prime. (Fermat's little theorem).

Answer (score 3):

This problem is well-known in combinatorics, you can look for example here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_(combinatorics)

The number of necklaces with $m$ beads and $n$ colors is $\frac{1}{m}\sum_{d|m}\phi(m/d)n^d$, where the sum is over all $d$ dividing $m$, and $\phi $ is Euler's totient function. When $m=p$ is a prime the sum has only two terms and it simplifies to $\frac{1}{p}(n^p+n p-n)$

Answer (score 1):

The closure mechanism (with a ring and a spike) gives such necklaces a beginning and an end. Striping one bead after the other over the spike onto the necklace you have $p$ choices from $n$ types of beads, makes $n^p$ "different" necklaces.

When the necklace is closed the closure is not seen any more. This implies that the  necklaces differing just by one of the $p$ rotations should be counted as the same. This leads to the conjecture that there are $N'={1\over p}n^p$  different necklaces. Now this $N'$ is (usually) not an integer. Where is the mistake?

There are $n$ special necklaces having all $p$ beads of the same color. Rotating such necklaces does not produce other necklaces and therefore overcounting. It follows that the correct number of different necklaces is
$$N={1\over p}(n^p-n) + n\ .$$
This $N$ is an integer, by Fermat's little theorem.